# Are paramiko file transfer operations atomic?

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I use `get` and `put` methods of `paramiko.SFTP` object. I can vaguely remember that I did at times get incomplete file contents with the `get` method, but never noticed any issue with `put`. Is it just my luck, or should I perform extra checks to ensure that I get the right files on the remote side? If so, how do I do it, given I only have SFTP access to that remote server?

By SFTP-only access, I mean I cannot SSH in:

```
$ ssh user@ipaddress
user@ipaddress's password: 
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
shell request failed on channel 0
```

Comment: I use `put` many times a day and I see files always arrive to the remote side. But if you want to be sure use `ssh.exec_command` and send any shell command you'd like (simple `ls` for example).

Comment: I meant the file contents, sorry. I updated the Question to clarify. Also, note that I don't have `exec_command` access to the server.

Comment: So it is not possible to SSH to the server?

Comment: You could sftp an md5 hash as a separate file. It would be somebody else's responsibility to check, but at least you got part way there. You could even get the file back and check the md5 - resending as needed. Basically, be your own verifier.

Comment: @tdelaney I thought of that as the solution... so ugly. Thanks for confirming I wasn't going too crazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can be fairly certain if an SFTP transfer completed without error or interruption, that the file has been fully copied over, since the SFTP protocol requires that each chunk sent be acknowledged. So, between the reliability of TCP, the SSH channel, and the ACKs from each chunk, it's very unlikely that the file has been truncated in any way.

A couple more things you could do when only using SFTP:

- After transfer, you can call `stat()` on the file to verify it's actual size.
- You could read back one or more chunks of the file and compare them locally.
- Some SFTP servers have a check-file extension (I don't think openssh supports this though). Paramiko sftp files have a `check()` method that allows you to get a hash of some or all of the file.

And to directly answer your question's title, transfers are *not* atomic. The file could still be altered on the system as it's being written. If you want to prevent against that, you could write the file to a temporary location remotely, verify it, then call `sftp.rename` to move it to it's final destination (which is an atomic operation on Linux within the same filesystem). That's roughly analogous to what **rsync** does, and probably as close as you can come to "atomic".